# What does pause button represent visually?

Tags: icons

Play is a triangle, reminding me of moving in some direction.
Fast Forward and Fast Rewind are usually double triangles which somehow remind me of their intensity in their directions.
Stop is like a block of concrete. I think of a dead-end seeing it.
But each and every time I see Pause icon, I fail to understand it visually. 
Of course we all recognize Pause button immediatly everywhere we see it. But I think that's just because we're used to it.
Is there any visual reasoning behind Pause icon?

Answer (score 3):

Relevant discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1tasqz/eli5_why_is_the_play_button_a_sideways_triangle/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/13v97g/til_that_the_pause_symbol_on_your_remote_control/)

> Play symbol symbolizes moving forward. Fast Forward symbol is thus
>   moving forward more. Rewind symbol is a backward play symbol, as it
>   represents moving backward. The Pause symbol indicates no movement
>   either forward nor backward. The stop symbol shows that there is no
>   action of any sort.

Another good explanation from same link trying get into history of symbology

> the pause button indicates the two rollers beside the read OR write
>   magnet on a tape deck that push the tape up against the head. the
>   single vertical bar with triangle indicates one roller retracted
>   faster play in that direction... basically other than the "play"
>   symbol, which simply means "go" the rest of the symbols are based on
>   the state of the controlling rollers. Record was a red circle,
>   indicating the red shelled "studio in use recording" light outside the
>   door.

and

> The vertical lines represent the sides of frames on a reel. Pause
>   means you are stopped between two frames, play means you are moving
>   through the frames left to right (hence the arrow), fast forward is
>   moving through the frames at some multiple of 1x, and the scene skip
>   button pushes you forward to some preset "hard" frame edge.

This one talks about how and where it originated

> The symbols for play, stop, pause and record — the original media
>   control symbols — were first introduced by Swedish Engineer Philip
>   Olsson. Olsson was working in Japan while finishing his studies at the
>   Royal Institute of Technology, having also earned a degree from a
>   Swedish design school.

and this

> It is likely a symbol derived from the [caesura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesura) sign used in musical
>   notation to indicate a pause. But it's origin is not known for sure.

And [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1tasqz/eli5_why_is_the_play_button_a_sideways_triangle/ce685ko) is an interesting comment from someone who claims to have seen the transition of this symbology.

Answer (score 0):

A simple metaphor with no historical provenance is that pause is a partial stop hence being a partial square. (It allowed a quick restart.)

This makes less sense when used in many digital applications now.